# Phase constant and angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

Is the formula true?

$$\langle l,m|L_+^2|l,m'\rangle=(-1)^{m+m'}\langle l,-m'|L_+^2|l,-m\rangle$$
I know how $L_+$ acts on the standard angular momentum state $|l,m\rangle$, but since
$$L_+|l,m\rangle=\hbar\sqrt{(l-m)(l-m+1)}|l,m+1\rangle$$ all coefficients are positive. How does the $(-1)$ factor come out?

Comment: Surely, for the matrix element to be non-zero $m$ and $m'$ must differ by two? If so $m+m'$ is an even number, making  $(-1)^{m+m'}=1$.

Comment: I think you are right… it really tricks me into thinking where the phase factor comes out but I never thought this factor is so trivial ..

Comment: @mikestone $m_1=-1/2, m_2=3/2$, $m_1+m_2=1$.

Comment: The trick is to use ${\cal P}=R_y(\pi)$,  Then 
$\langle \ell m \vert {\cal P}{\cal P}^{-1}(L_+)^2 {\cal P}{\cal P}^{-1}\vert \ell m’\rangle=\langle \ell m\vert L_+^2 \vert \ell m’\rangle$ and ${\cal P}^{-1}\vert \ell m’\rangle=(-1)^{m’}\vert \ell -m’\rangle$.  I’m not sure about the phase $(-1)^{m’}$ and I will check at some later time.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero.  Good point about the half integers,  but is not $P^{-1} L_+^2 P= L_-^2$? The rotation abou the $y$ axix takes then $J_x$ in $J_+= J_x+iJ_y$ to $-J_x$.

Comment: @mikestone I checked my phases and indeed I needed to use $P^{-1}L_+^2P=L_-^2$.  I don't see how the suggested equality holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the proposed equality is true under the usual phase convention for $L_\pm$.

The simplest way to see this is to realize that the matrix elements of $L_\pm$, and thus the matrix elements of $L^2_\pm$, are necessarily positive with the usual choice of phase, so $\langle \ell,m\vert L^2_\pm \vert \ell m'\rangle$ is necessarily always positive for any $m,m'$: there cannot be a sign flip.

More formally, start by observing that
\begin{align}
R_y(\pi)\vert \ell,m\rangle&=(-1)^{\ell-m} \vert \ell, -m\rangle \\
R_y(-\pi)\vert \ell,m\rangle&=(-1)^{\ell+m} \vert \ell, m\rangle
\end{align}
and then note that
\begin{align}
\langle \ell m\vert L_+^2 \vert \ell m'\rangle &=
\langle \ell m\vert R_y(-\pi)R_y(\pi) L_+^2 R_y(-\pi)R_y(\pi)\vert \ell,m'\rangle\\
&= \langle \ell m \vert R_y(-\pi) \vert\ell -m\rangle
\langle \ell -m \vert R_y(\pi) L_+^2 R_y(-\pi) \vert \ell, -m'\rangle (-1)^{\ell-m'}\\
&= \langle \ell,-m\vert R_y(\pi) L_+^2 R_y(-\pi) \vert \ell,-m'\rangle (-1)^{\ell-m'}(-1)^{\ell+m}
\end{align}
Next, observe that $R_y(\pi) L_+^2 R_y(-\pi) =L_-^2$ so that we now have
\begin{align}
\langle \ell m\vert L_+^2 \vert \ell m'\rangle&=(-1)^{m-m'}
\langle \ell,-m\vert L_-^2\vert \ell,-m'\rangle \\
&= 
(-1)^{m-m'} \langle \ell, -m'\vert L_+^2\vert \ell,-m\rangle
\end{align}
since the matrix elements of $L_\pm$ are real, but of course we must also have $m'+2=m$ or $m-m'=2$ so the phase factor $(-1)^{m-m'}$ goes away.

We can redo this with $\langle \ell,m\vert L_+ \vert \ell m'\rangle$ instead.  In this case, we have $R_y(\pi)L_+R_y(-\pi)=-L_-$ so the overall phase is then $(-1)^{m-m'+1}$, with $m'+1=m$ so that $(-1)^{m-m'+1}=1$ always.

Note also that $L_\pm$ are related to the components of the tensor operator $T^{1}_{\pm 1}=\frac{\mp 1}{\sqrt{2}}L_\pm$, and we have $
L_\pm ^2\sim T^{2}_{\pm 2}$ so while other components of the tensor operator $T^{2}_m$ may pick up a phase under reflection the $\pm 2$ components cannot.